# Can I perform actions with fewer permissions than I'm otherwise granted?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Not really sure how to word this question, so I'll give an example:

On my VSTS project, I have administrator-level permissions, meaning that I can manage all the branches, the repository, etc. I need these permissions so that, in urgent cases, I can address issues on the repository without going through our normal branch policy procedure.

I almost never need these rights, but I need them for that 1% case.

I'm also a contributor to the repository, and in 99% of cases, I want to be bound by the same branch policy and security restrictions as every other contributor. One simple example is 'force push'. Normal contributors only have force-push rights to branches that they initially pushed to the repo (they 'own' it).

I happen to have force-push rights to our 'release' branch for the reasons stated above. I would like to avoid accidentally doing a push --force on this branch (or a bypass-branch-policy push, which is equally dangerous).

Basically, is there a way that I can switch my local git configuration to have some sort of 'least privilege' mode where I can't do something destructive, while still having the ability to elevate to more privileges when the time calls for it?

I tried checking in the authorization tokens tab, but this seems too coarse. Either I can push to the repo or not, no further nuance possible.

I wanted to avoid going down the road of having a separate user that has these elevated privileges since it would reduce our audit-ability unless we created one 'elevated-user' per real user.

Are there some alternatives available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to configure a group that can manage the permissions of the Project Admin/Collection Admin groups and be a member of that group, that way you can always temporarily add yourself into that group for that 1% of tasks. At the same time you'll always be a normal contributor with normal rights.

Alternatively, have a second account created for you, something like jeff-admin@yourcompany.com and switch accounts or use the browser's in-private mode to do your admin work.

There is no "limited admin mode" in VSTS by default in which you can temporarily bump your project admin permissions, it'd be a nice suggestion for the VSTS [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) website.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. The admin-user was (and still is) a last resort to me. 

Your first suggestion made me realize that there's nothing inherent in VSTS's permissions system that states collection-level administrators must also have super-admin rights to repositories in projects. It's just a particular detail that's true about our own configuration. So I'm starting the discussion to change that, likely toward what you suggested with the separate group.

I may also suggest a 'sudo' sort of thing on UserVoice, but this will probably meet my initial concerns just fine.